# Home/Index not found. Can't I use a constraint?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the classic default ASP.NET MVC route:

```
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
  );
```

Because I would like to have another HomeController inside an area I added the following:

```
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
      typeof(MVCSite.Controllers.HomeController).Assembly
  );
```

So that this route is only for the root home controller.

But when I start the site with this I get a 404 error.

Why is that? Can't I specify this constraint?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you have a class that inherits from AreaRegistration and override the RegisterArea() method?

Comment: No. In fact I do not have any areas at the moment. But I will add one with a HomeController. So I just added the constraint before adding the area. And I get the 404 error ... Not sure why

Comment: If I use the constructor that takes the String[] namespaces and use new String[] typeof(MVCSite.Controllers.HomeController).Namespace then it works fine. Not sure why I am not able to use the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", 
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
  new String[] { typeof(HomeController).Namespace 
});
```

Thank You,
Miguel